# Multiple Integration: where's the mistake in my process?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate:
$$ \iiint_{D}\sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
where D is the domain:

$$D: x^2 +4y^2+9z^2\le1$$

Can someone tell me if my steps are correct?

$$\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \, dz\iint_{\{ \frac{x^2}{1-9z^2}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{1}{4}(1-9z^2)} \le1 \}}\sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)} \,dx\,dy $$

The last double integral is composed by the following integrals:
$$\int_{-\sqrt{1-9z^2}}^{+\sqrt{1-9z^2}} \, dx \int_{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}}^{+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}}\,\sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)} dy$$

Since both integral don't depend on $z$ I can write:$$ \iiint_{D}f\,dx\,dy\,dz=2\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{1-9z^2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}\,dz \int_{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}}^{+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}}\sqrt{1-4y^2-9z^2}\,dy$$
Here I've already done the first integral which depends on $x$.

So we have to calculate:$$\int_{\frac{-1}{2}a}^{\frac{1}{2}a} \sqrt{a^2-4y^2}\, dy$$ where $a^2=1-9z^2$; we can consider $a$ as a constant.
Now let $y=\frac{1}{2}asin(t)$, we have:
$$dy=\frac{1}{2}acos(t)dt$$ The last integral I wrote turns into:$$\frac{1}{2}a^2\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{+\pi}{2}}\left | cos(t) \right |cos(t)dt$$ which can be written as:$$a^2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}cos^2(t)dt=a^2\left [ \frac{t}{2} +\frac{sin(t)cos(t)}{2}\right ]\begin{matrix} \frac{\pi}{2} \\0\end{matrix}=\frac{\pi}{4}a^2$$

Finally:$$ \iiint_{D}f\,dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{1}{3}}(1-9z^2)^2\,dz$$

In my schoolbook the solution is $\frac{64}{135}$...so where is the mistake in my method?

Comment: The formula after "The last double integral is composed by..." is wrong, because you are integrating over an ellipsis, so the integration limits cannot depends only on $z$.

Comment: Shouldn't both x and y go from the negative semi axis to the positive semi axis of the ellipsis?

Comment: I think they must depend on z...

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution
\begin{align}
x &= \bar{x}\\
y &= \frac{1}{2}\bar{y}\\
z &= \frac{1}{3}\bar{z}
\end{align}
the integral becomes
$$
I=\frac{1}{6}\iiint_\bar{D}\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}\sqrt{1-\bar{y}^2-\bar{z}^2}d\bar{x}d\bar{y}d\bar{z}
$$
where $|J|=1/6$.
Now you have
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{6}\int_{-1}^{+1}d\bar{z}\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}}^{+\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}}d\bar{y}\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-\bar{y}^2-\bar{z}^2}}^{+\sqrt{1-\bar{y}^2-\bar{z}^2}}d\bar{x}\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}\sqrt{1-\bar{y}^2-\bar{z}^2}\right)\right)\\
  &= \frac{1}{3}\int_{-1}^{+1}d\bar{z}\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}}^{+\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}}d\bar{y}\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}(1-\bar{y}^2-\bar{z}^2)\right)\\
  &= \frac{4}{9}\int_{-1}^{+1}d\bar{z}(1-\bar{z}^2)^2=\frac{64}{135}
\end{align}